# How do i prevent my program from queing button presses

Tags: android, audio, nested-loops, thread-sleep, vibration

Hi everyone This is my first post so please be gentle.  Even though my android final is complete and all i still find it hard to not continue to adjust my program and add to it just for the fun of it. what it is is a simple program that when you touch the screen the character on the screen laughs one of two ways with matching vibration. It works nicely but when my teacher (who was in a foul mood at the time) went to test it he pretty much button mashed the thing which made it que up every button press and we had to sit through like 15 laughter fits before we could do anything more with the phone. What i want to do is just have one touch event count until the first event is complete. what it is is a simple on touch event with a couple nested if statements.

```
public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent m) 
    {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.laughing);//changes the image to the laughing monkey
            if (m.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                if (timesTouched != I) //checks to see if the touch amount is not equal to the random number
                {
                    if(laughter != 0) 
                    {       
                        sp.play(laughter, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);//plays the loaded sound when the screen is pressed
                        //vib.vibrate(900);
                    }
                    Time = 900;
                    timesTouched++;
                    intDelay = 1;
                    if(vibon == 1)
                    {
                        vib.vibrate(Time);
                    }
                }

                else if (timesTouched == I)//checks to see if the touch amount is the same as the random number
                {
                    if(laughter != 0)
                    {
                        sp.play(laughFit, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);//plays the loaded sound when the screen is pressed
                    }
                    Time = 6000;
                    timesTouched = 0;
                    intDelay = 1;
                    if(vibon == 1)
                    {
                        vib.vibrate(laugh, -1);
                    }
                }

            }

            else if((m.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) && (intDelay == 1))
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Time);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal) ;//returns the image to the normal looking monkey
                intDelay = 0;
            }
        return true;
    }
}
```

the sleep timer is there to prevent the background image from going back to the default before the laughter is over. I did attempt to get my teacher to help but he is just a speedy replacement and had never even touched an android device before starting to teach at the beginning of this year. please any help you can provide is greatly appreciated because so far i have had to pretty much teach myself this stuff with the help of Google searches.

Thanks a Bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If this were me I would probably move the sound playing to a separate thread then use messages to notify that thread when to start and stop the sounds. In this way the button can send the message immediately and not be blocked by any subsequent actions. The side-effect should be that every button press stops the previous laughter and starts a new one (or just queues up another sound byte over the previous one effectively combining sounds). You could contrarily disable the button until the sound is finished but I do not believe that would be a good user experience - they would expect to be able to mash and mash to their hearts content!

Check out http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html for more guidance on how to approach such a thing.

Comment: Thank you I haven't had a lot of experience with threading so I will have to d some reading and research to learn more Thank you for the link to get me started. If anyone else has any ideas I would love to read them.

Comment: You generally don't want blocking items running in the UI thread (where a button even is). Instead those blocking items should be in a separate thread so it can run independently without one waiting for the other. Once you figure it out it's pretty easy to get going with. Good luck.